# diskutil mountDisk with password

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, external-hard-drive, mount

I'm trying to mount a disk with password from the terminal, i try:

diskutil mount Harddrive

I Get:

Unable to find disk for Harddrive

This is because the disk isn't in Volumes until i entered the password,

How to enter the password from terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the command you want is unlockVolume:

```
diskutil unlockVolume lvUUID [-stdinpassphrase] | [-passphrase passphrase] | [-recoverykeychain file]
```

more details are here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8